# Displaying data from a "grandchild" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of building a rails app that compiles and organizes campaign finance data in local elections.

I've run into a bit of a wall in a way I want to have a certain data set display.

I have three classes:

District
Candidate
Report (there are many of these added over time)

Candidate belongs to district. Report belongs to candidate. On the district page, I have a list of all the candidates who are running in that district, along with columns showing their party, etc. As part of that display, I would like to add columns that pull data from the MOST RECENT report (namely, "cash_on_hand").

Now, I've been able to successfully show all the candidates running in that district by adding "@candidates = @district.candidates" to the districts controller...and I assume grabbing the data I need is also done from the controller...but I'm stuck on how to basically pull data from the "grandchild" in this case. I've tried a few different random attempts, hoping that one might work, but have not been successful. I imagine this is fairly easy to solve, but I'm still in the process of learning rails, so your patience and understanding is appreciated!

Comment: The most recent report for the district, or for the candidate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Candidate belongs to district. Report belongs to candidate.

You should have something like this.

```
class District
  has_many :candidates
  has_many :reports through: :candidates
end

class Candidate
  belongs_to :district
  has_many :reports
end

class Report
  belongs_to :candidate
  delegate :district, to: :candidate
end
```

To get the most recent report...

```
@candidates.each do |candidate|
  report = candidate.reports.order(created_at: :desc).first
  ...
end
```

This, or something very similar, would probably be in the view where it can be done iteratively. Otherwise the controller has to pull all the Candidates and all their Reports into memory.

You can push this down into the model, not the controller they should be "thin", as an [association extension](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions).

```
class Candidate
  belongs_to :district
  has_many :reports do
    def most_recent
      order(created_at: :desc).first
    end
  end
end
```

Then the view would...

```
@candidates.each do |candidate|
  report = candidate.reports.most_recent
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked beautifully. However, I have another grouping that also has reports that is similar to candidates: Incumbents. Is there a syntax to create multiple "through" and "delegate" associations? I thought it might be "delegate :district, to: :candidate :incumbent "...but that didn't work.

Comment: @mph372 `delegate :district, to: :candidate :incumbent` says the method `district` should be both `candidate.district` and `incumbent.district` which does not make sense. A Report can be for one Candidate which can only be for one District. I suspect a District (not a Report) has a Candidate which is the incumbent. You'd write a method in District to get its incumbent as an extension to `has_many :candidates`. Then to get the reports for the incumbent Candidate of a District: `district.candidates.incumbent.reports`.